# Styling the <a> tags inside <ul> <li>

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a hover effect when user moves the mouse over one of the menu links.

I would also like a bit of space between each line in the menu.

Is there a way to add this to `.menuitems` or will I have to add a class to each of the elements inside the `<ul>` scope?

**CSS :**

```
.menuitems {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    color: #337AB7;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
}

a:hover .menuitems {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<md-menu-content>
    <ul class="menuitems">
        <li md-ink-ripple>
            <a ui-sref="book">New Booking</a>
        </li>
        <li md-ink-ripple>
            <a ui-sref="admin.home">Admin</a>
        </li>
        <li md-ink-ripple>
            <a ui-sref="admin_logout">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</md-menu-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following CSS selector, to refer to the `<a>`

```
.menuitems li a:hover
```

For adding space after the lines you can use margins.

```
.menuitems li {
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

See for reference : [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
.menuitems {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  color: #337AB7;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
}

.menuitems li a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.menuitems li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuitems">
  <li md-ink-ripple>
    <a ui-sref="book">New Booking</a>
  </li>
  <li md-ink-ripple>
    <a ui-sref="admin.home">Admin</a>
  </li>
  <li md-ink-ripple>
    <a ui-sref="admin_logout">Logout</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice Rithwik!! - I actually tried `menuitems a:hover{` but couldnt get that to work.

Comment: You have to go systematically not that `<a>` are not direct descendants of `.menuitems`, so it would be `.menuitems li a:hover`.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! okie - now I get it - so you "nest" your way down to the element you want to style - okie, very useful!!

Comment: Precisely! I've added a reference link on [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), also added space between the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Remove class name from hover css will give you yellow background color and add padding-bottom will give you extra space. 
[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/aLy8Lw7j/3/)

CSS :

```
.menuitems {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    color: #337AB7;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
}
.menuitems li {
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.menuitems li a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: except, now all links on my website have the hover effect heheh

Comment: ha ha ... @Rithwik answer will do the trick for you .. but padding will give you sapce... xD

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.menuitems` from a:hover `.menuitems`.

**CSS**

```
.menuitems {
font-size: 20px;
font-family: 'Roboto';
color: #337AB7;
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 180px;
}
/*For hover */
    a:hover{
        background-color: yellow;       
    }
/* To make space between two lines */
    li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

It will work.